# Connecting two docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have two existing docker container web and db. I want to link these two container, so that they will communicate with each other. If i go with --link command means it will link web to a new image and not to the db.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Using `--link` was the only way of connecting containers before the advent of docker networks. These provide a "cleaner" solution to the problem of inter-container communication and at the same time solves 2 of the major limits of links:

1. restart of linked container breaks the link
2. links are not supported between containers running on different hosts

Using docker network you would use the `--net` option to start the containers on the specified network:

```
docker network create example
docker run -d --net example --name container1 <image>
docker run -d --net example --name container2 <image>
```

At this point the 2 container are mutually reachable via the address `<container-name>.example`: that is `container1.example` and `container2.example`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now I got it.

Comment: `--link` is deprecated now! I though really appreciate the example of --net. Will try it out.

Comment: Using --net it will come under a specific IP. But both the containers have different IPs like a Subnet IPs. Eg : Network IP is 180.12.10.0 means, container IP will be 180.12.10.1 and 180.12.10.2 respectively?

Comment: Great answer. The address description was what I was struggling with: `<container-name>.example:<port>` was what I needed to get this going without docker-compose.

Answer (score 5):

Just to benefit people that stumble upon this question. The `--link` feature is now considered legacy and is a prime candidate to be deprecated by docker.
The easiest way is to use

```
depends_on:
```

In order to do this, its recommended to first create a network like so:

```
docker network create <network_name>
```

Then use docker-compose to spawn services that bind with each other. Look at the example below where I've bound my spring-boot app to rabbit-mq. You can clone my repo from [here](https://github.com/pbushan/resolute-hub.git).

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  rabbitmq-container:
    image: rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
    hostname: rabbitmq-container
    ports:
      - 5673:5673
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - resolute

  resolute-container:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - spring_rabbitmq_host=rabbitmq-container
      - spring_rabbitmq_port=5672
      - spring_rabbitmq_username=guest
      - spring_rabbitmq_password=guest
      - resolute_rabbitmq_publishQueueName=resolute-run-request
      - resolute_rabbitmq_exchange=resolute
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq-container
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - resolute

networks:
  resolute:
    external:
      name: resolute
```

See how I've created a network called `resolute` and bound the apps to the same network. I've also given my rabbitmq-container a `hostname`. This is because docker now prepends the container name and that makes it difficult to bind services by name.

Comment: Is there a limit of how many networks can exist on a docker host?

Answer (score -2):

`link` is used to connect containers so that they can communicate with each other once the communication is establish they will be able to communicate with your database.

Comment: I nearly discouraged this answer, while I normally never discourage answers. You schould provide more exemplary stuff, and the word link is nor a cli-option and nor do I know, where to use that option ...

Comment: sure, thanks for the guidance will make sure I follow.