# How to connect to rabbitmq in one docker container from a service sitting in another

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, containers

I am starting a container for rabbitmq and another with my spring boot service using the following docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  messaging:
    image: "messaging"
    ports: 
     - "7878:9876"
    depends_on:
     - rmq
  rmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:management"
    hostname: "rabbitmqhost"
    container_name: "rabbit-mq"
    ports: 
     - "15672:15672"
     - "5672:5672"
```

Now rabbitmq management is accessible at `http://localhost:15672/` and the service is accessible at `http://localhost:7878`

The service is supposed to push messages into rabbitmq. When I hit the restAPI `http://localhost:7878/sendPersonDetails` it is unable to connect to rabbitmq.

Following is the error response I am getting-

`error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@3e66d8c7]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

Following is my `application.properties` file-

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=person
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.content-type=application/json

server.port=9876
```

How do I change my docker-compose configuration or service configuration to make it work? Any help's appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to docker-compose, you can access rmq container by the service name (http://rabbit-mq:port) from the other container. No need to expose ports either.

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `localhost` inside the rabbitmq container is not the same `localhost` you see from your host machine. Indeed every container has a `localhost` address which point to its IP.

The way to connect container together is to use *docker networks*. See this other answer for more details: [Connecting two docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481943/connecting-two-docker-containers/45483915#45483915)