# The application server has been running in docker container could not use postgresql dirver.Connection refused

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, intellij-idea, jdbc

I am trying to use JDBC from first container  to connect to Postgresql database on secend container .the error happens while trying to make a database connection.

`conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);`

I deploy war file into wildfly that is docker container.
when I call the connect() method the error  occur.
**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.corsan</groupId>
    <artifactId>corsan</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**docker file**:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD corsan.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

the Java code for JDBC connection:

```java
private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
private final String user = "postgres";
private final String password = "1234";


    public Connection connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("problem while making connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

and while the wildfly is lunching there is always this warning that I guess is relevant to the connection refused Error:

> Could not index class org/postgresql/jdbc/PgConnection$1.class at
> /content/corsan.war/WEB-INF/lib/postgresql-42.2.16.jar:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required class information is missing

these two picture are intellij project structure and artifact that has postgres driver library in its lib.
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXjRs.png)
[Project structure Artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C960i.png)

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
22:51:20,921 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) 
  UT005023: Exception handling request to /corsan/: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when I deploy the war directly to the same application server in local it works fine. But when I use docker container this issue occure. I appreciate for any hint or help.

Postgresql and application server are running in separate container in local machine.
docker ps :

> app server port: 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
> PG: 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp

Comment: try 'docker ps' make sure your port is being forwarded from your host machine to the docker container, you need to see something like 5432->5432

Comment: In a docker container `localhost` is the container itself (not the host). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) for info on referencing the host (If Postgres is also a container then you can [connect to it directly](https://docs.docker.com/network/))

Comment: Please post formatted code rather than screenshots. Screenshots break search, copy and paste, and are less accessible.

Comment: @ScottFree  the docker ps command show this app server port: 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
PG: 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp that looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **application server** and **Postgresql database** are in two separate **containers** so they need to be connected together. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483915/5848056) help to make network between two separate container.Also [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/installation/) can be used as GUI tools for connecting different containers together.
After these two containers have a same network we can check it with this command to ensure that the both containers are using the same network(corsannet is the name of network that I used).

```
docker network inspect corsannet
```

To ensure that  the both containers are using the same network.

The other issue is for **JDBC** url we can not use <s>localhost</s> or domain name instead we should use the name of the database container, in this sample is **pg**.

```java
private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://pg:5432/postgres";
```