# Cannot connect SMTP between two Docker containers

Tags: docker, email, smtp, discourse

I have read:

[Connecting two docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481943/connecting-two-docker-containers)

[How to get Docker containers to talk to each other while running on my local host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093812/how-to-get-docker-containers-to-talk-to-each-other-while-running-on-my-local-hos)

I have two docker stacks running behind an nginx proxy.

- discourse (trying to send mails).
- mailu (full email stack, Listens on 0.0.0.0:587)

The mail server works perfectly for everything coming from and going to outside.
Discourse works, with the one exception that emails cannot be sent via the smtp in mailu.

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE  
2492bbae4093        bridge              bridge              local  
5eef88cc8484        host                host                local  
f8c0d60ec0a2        mailu_default       bridge              local  
7483f57ce6d3        none                null                local
```

From the host:

```
nc -v mydomain.de 587
Connection to mydomain.de 587 port [tcp/submission] succeeded!
```

Same from outside: `connection succeeded`

From inside the Discourse container:

```
mydomain.de [172.17.0.2] 587 (smtp) : Connection refused
mydomain.de [172.17.0.2] 12345 (?) : Connection refused (This is a non-existing port for cross-test)
```

I assume I have to create a shared connection between the containers, but could not get the syntax right.