# Login failed for user 'sa' - Docker Compose SQL Server connection issue

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I'm trying to connect SQL Server to ASP.NET Core in a Docker container, but this error happens, even after being guided by answers to similar problems:

```
2023-12-20 21:04:49 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
2023-12-20 21:04:49       An error occurred using the connection to database 'CinemaDatabase' on server 'sql,1433'.
2023-12-20 21:04:49 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
2023-12-20 21:04:49       An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Backend.Context.AccountDBContext'.
2023-12-20 21:04:49       Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'.
2023-12-20 21:04:49          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
2023-12-20 21:04:49          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
2023-12-20 21:04:49          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
2023-12-20 21:04:49          at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
```

My docker-compose file looked like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "7238:7238"
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=sql,1433;Database=CinemaDatabase;User=sa;Password=S3nh@V@lid4;TrustServerCertificate=True;
    depends_on:
      - sql
  sql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: sql_server
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
      - SA_PASSWORD="S3nh@V@lid4"
```

Comment: make sure the containers are on the same network.  you'll probably want to explicitly set them in the docker file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481943/connecting-two-docker-containers

Comment: Where are you creating or restoring the `CinemaDatabase` database? You don't seem to be doing anything like using `entrypoint.sh` or `setup.sql` scripts as mentioned in the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/mssql/server/about#usage).

Comment: Aside... not the cause of your problem (yet) but the `SA_PASSWORD` environment variable has been deprecated for some time. You're meant to be using the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable instead. See the Docker Hub link in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After following what you said, I made good progress and I can even connect to the database through SSMS, but my Asp Net Core still suffers from a SA user login failure, which is what I'm using in SSMS.
this is my current string: - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=sql_server,1433;Database=CinemaApp;User Id=SA;Password=S3nh@V@lid4;Integrated Security=false; TrustServerCertificate=true

Comment: STOP using the SA user to access databases!!!

Comment: Why shouldn't I use it in a development environment?

Comment: Because...it then often happens that in a rush to production, the same user is used. Get into good habits.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours and sleepless nights, I managed to solve it. I needed to add EnableRetryOnFailure() to my instance. Like this:

```
  builder.Services.AddDbContext<AccountDBContext>(options =>
  {
      options.UseSqlServer(
          builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
          sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure());
  });
```

In my entrypoint.sh file, I thought I gave SQL Server enough time to get ready, but I still needed to add this for the SA user login error to stop.